# Return all results (including null) when SQL stored procedure parameter is null

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, parameters, isnull

I have SQL table that contains null values for ex:

| ID | NAME | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 123 |
| 2 | Doe | 456 |
| 3 | Soe | *NULL* |

I want to check if the where clause parameter is null then return all table, what I tried:

```
@devCode int = NULL

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CODE = ISNULL(@devCode, CODE)
```

But the last row (ID 3) gets excluded when @devCode = NULL. I want that to be included too in result when the parameter is null.

p.s. I also tried IIF and CASE but the result is the same.

Comment: This is how null works... Doesn't match anything including null.

Comment: @SalmanA yes I learned that facing this, and I also learned that SET ANSI_NULLS OFF fix the problem nut it's not recommended to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will work

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE CODE = @devCode OR @devCode IS Null
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I didn't think about it this way, I tried something similar but didn't work as expected: WHERE CODE = @devCode OR CODE IS Null
Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome happy coding